# x509 Certs in .NET - Difference between PrivateKey XML-values and Cert RawData

Tags: security, encryption, .net-4.0, x509certificate2

I'm considering a Symmetric Encryption scheme that uses an encryption key that itself derives from an X509 certificate.  I realize this is not Asymmetric, and perhaps odd, but its an experiment.

My goal is to access the private key, or some portion, from the x509 Certificate as input to a "key" derivation function.

Dumb question:  What property on the `x509Certificate2` *is* the private key?  The `PrivateKey` is itself just the alrogithm.  The algorithm's `ToXmlString` enumerates several values (`Modulus, Exponent, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ, D`) that I suspect are vendor specific.  Also the `x509Certificate2.RawData` is available.

When talking about the Encrypt-with-public-key / decrypt-with-private-key Asymmetric algorithm...which of the above properties, if any, is that private-key?

Thanks in advance,

Howard Hoffman

Comment: I'm thinking that the XmlString contains the "private key", in either the 'D' or 'Modulus' elements.  

Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: From your question it sounds a little like you're throwing a bunch of crypto and .NET concepts into a blender and hitting the "liquefy" button. That can be fun, but it makes it hard to understand and answer your question. Are you familiar with the RSA algorithm? [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/RSA) is a reasonable place to start if not.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the answer to my question is the PrivateKey is not a scalar or single value, but the result of an algorithm applied to data, where that data is expressed by the `ToXmlString` property on the AsymmetricAlgorithm object.  That's just my high-level take; without delving much into the details of RSA.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx the PrivateKey property is a link to the private key and not the algorithm.

See also the example on the provided link to see how to print the private key.

Comment: Note that the data-type of PrivateKey is indeed 'AsymmetricAlgorithm'. That's what I meant when I said that "The `PrivateKey` is itself just the alrogithm. "